# JButtons disappear after the popup menu shows

Tags: java, swing, popup, jbutton, popupmenu

I added listeners to my JButtons for the popup menu but when the popup menu appears the JButtons disappear and I would need to hover my cursor on the buttons to make them appear again. Why is it like this?

(all the methods here are in the same class)

```
public Inventory() {
    setLayout(null);
    setBounds(0, 0, 175, 210);
    
    initPopupMenu(); // this just sets what is inside the popup menu
    int x;
            // 30 buttons
    for(x = 0; x < 30; x++) {
        button[x] = new JButton();
        add(button[x]);
        button[x].addMouseListener(this);
    }

    x = 0;
            // it's a grid of buttons
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            button[x].setBounds(i*35+1,j*35+1, 33,33);  
            x++;
        }
    
    
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 30; j++) // i tried this one but it still disappears
        button[j].repaint();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        if(e.getSource() == button[i]) {
            System.out.println("You pressed Button "+i);
            popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

This is what happens, [image: jbuttons]
<sub>(source: [uploadir.com](https://uploadir.com/u/115577))</sub>

[image: popup]
<sub>(source: [uploadir.com](https://uploadir.com/u/4h9t6n))</sub>

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some code that includes how you create the buttons and the menus. Does the menu hide the button, or do they just "dissapear" ?

Comment: *"Why is it like this?"*  Because of the code used.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You can add some code so we can understand what is wrong.

Comment: @RahulBorkar *"to receive something personally from you"*  It does not count for much, but you already have.  I regularly see answers from you that make me think *"Great answer, now I don't have to deal with that.  +1"*.  ;)

Comment: *"all the methods here are in the same class"*  Thanks for the edit, but note that I still think you are more likely to get help by posting an **SSCCE**, rather than uncompilable code snippets.

Comment: my class implements the mouse listener of course

Comment: @AndrewThompson ok. sorry, I'm new here

Comment: No need to be sorry.  We were all new at one stage, and some very experienced folk have not heard of an SSCCE.  :)  (In addition to that, many code problems ***are solved*** without an SSCCE.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop using `null` Layout, seems like that can be one of the issues regarding this. Your `JFrame` appears sort of `BLACK` to me, is this some `THEME` or a new `LOOK AND FEEL` you are using, that can be the cause of this thing too. Here check this out, it's working flawlessly here with this code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonPopUp
{
    private static final int SIZE = 30;
    private JButton[] button = new JButton[SIZE];
    private JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu("Hello World");

    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button POP UP Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

        final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 5));

        JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Menu Item 1");
        JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Menu Item 2");
        //popup.add(greetings);
        popup.insert(menuItem1, 0);
        popup.insert(menuItem2, 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            button[i] = new JButton();
            button[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
            button[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
            {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
                {
                    System.out.println("I am WORKING!!");
                    popup.show((JComponent)me.getSource(), me.getX(), me.getY());
                }
            });
            contentPane.add(button[i]);
        }

        frame.getContentPane().add(contentPane);
        frame.setSize(175, 250);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new ButtonPopUp().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the output :

[image: Before Event] [image: After Event]

Comment: @Stephan : Thankyou and Keep Smiling :-) , that `LnF` can be another culprit :(

Comment: This would become even nicer and more dynamically if you use a `JTable` with custom cells. ;-)

Comment: The black grid behind the buttons is just because of paint method. Thank you very much! I will experiment with this code.

Comment: @Marvin : Try this latest code, I had added Border to it, why you using `paint(...)` method, any specific reason for that, since in `Swing` never override `paint(...)` always override `paintComponent(...)` if the said `JComponent` has one. You are MOST Welcome and Keep Smiling :-)

Comment: Ok I will take note of that, but why should you never override paint? I'd just like to ask. And also calling repaint() calls paint() not paintComponent(), am I right? or not? I'm just a beginner in Java. :)

Comment: More than me, [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/problems.html) can help you on this, why `paintComponent(...)`